# Scraping the Google Infobox

Tags: php, node.js, web-scraping

I a trying to get some information from the infobox that is shown in Google results page (for example: https://www.google.fr/search?q=einstein )

Apparently, the infoxbox is not part of the page served back .. i have tried the following methods:

- Node.js using Cheerio
- Phantom.js to capture a screenshot
- PHP using CuRL or file_get_contents

I would appreciate any heads up ..

Thanks a lot

Comment: I can see the infobox content when viewing page-source in chrome

Comment: @levi yes .. it is loaded in the page but apparently this is done dynamically .. the infobx will not be shown if you do a curl for example .. i have even tried to use headless browser emulators .. but still no luck

Comment: `view-source:` does not show dynamic content, yet it shows info from the box, eg: spouse. Are you sure you are parsing it correctly?

Comment: sorry my bad .. it is shown in the view:source .. and even in the networks panel in the dev tools it is returned in the response .. but then .. i cannot understand why it will not show in curl or any other method i have tried .. i am not even parsing the page .. i just request and print it directly .. and no infoxbox is shown

Comment: Perhaps Google is serving different content based on useragent?

Comment: I can confirm, google does not serve the infobox when loading the URL in IE7. So it seems its dependent on the user-agent.

Comment: thanks a lot @levi .. mimicking the user agent did the trick :) i'd be glad to accept the answer if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google may be serving different content based on the user-agent. Try setting the user-agent of your request to that of the chrome browser, and see if that helps.